# Settings to allow Rygel through ufw firewall

Tags: media, ps3, rygel

I have installed Rygel as per (https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/installing-rygel-2.6-dev-on-ubuntu20-04.html) I have also installed Rygel Preferences. The media server is blocked by my ufw firewall. I have tried allowing port 1900 udp & tcp, 65530tcp, 34567tcp, 8200tcp & also edited the configuration port to run http to 34567. Non of these settings work, please help. I am using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

(sudo ufw allow from ip address of PS3) This works but the PS3 is allocated a different ip address by DHCP each time it boots up. I can not set a static ip address as I am using a vodafone hub, I would have to pay for a static ip address.
Pictures and music work fine, but videos are not watchable. ubuntu-restricted-extras are installed, but I guess that's just yet another issue to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the port 1900, In my case I found which port is required by looking the blocked requests in ufw while trying to access the media server from my other device.

View ufw log by running `tail -f /var/log/ufw.log`

```
Dec 10 15:57:42 emmerson-desktop kernel: [ 7532.241616] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp8s0 OUT= MAC=***** SRC=192.168.0.248 DST=192.168.0.108 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54538 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53318 DPT=35727 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Filter your ufw log by source and destination IP or the mac address of your device as there may be lot of entries from different devices/services.

As you see, in my case, my other device(SRC=192.168.0.248) was trying to access my desktop's media server(DST=192.168.0.108) on destination port `35727` and the request was blocked.

I then opened up port `35727 TCP` on ufw after which I was able to share my media.